# The Kernel crashed while executing code when trying to load gan model

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, out-of-memory, generative-adversarial-network

so I have a gan model where my input is an image of size `1*64*64` and their are 229 conditioning labels, when I tried to load the model `critic, generator = Critic().to("cuda"), Generator().to("cuda")` even without dataset its throwing memory error. I have tried changing the `conditioning_embedding` size but no use still the same error. I have tried to see what's happening using `htop` when ever I load the model the memory usage is jumping from 8GB to 30GB.

I have tried to write a simple logits models which is similar to critic, given an image predicts the label, their I dont have the problem but here in this model I am facing it why

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Hyperparameter:
    num_classes: int        = 229
    batchsize: int          = 16
    num_epochs: int         = 20
    latent_size: int        = 100  # Increased for more complex data
    n_critic: int           = 5
    critic_size: int        = 29 * 29 * 64  # Updated based on the Critic's CNN output size
    generator_size: int     = 29 * 29 * 64  # Same as critic_size for symmetry
    critic_hidden_size: int = 1024  # Arbitrarily chosen, can be tuned
    gp_lambda: float        = 10.0  # Commonly used value for WGAN-GP

hp = Hyperparameter()

class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.latent_embedding = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(hp.latent_size, hp.generator_size // 2),
        )
        self.condition_embedding = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(hp.num_classes, hp.generator_size // 2),
        )
        self.tcnn = nn.Sequential(
        nn.ConvTranspose2d( hp.generator_size, hp.generator_size, 4, 1, 0),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(hp.generator_size),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d( hp.generator_size, hp.generator_size // 2, 3, 2, 1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(hp.generator_size // 2),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d( hp.generator_size // 2, hp.generator_size // 4, 4, 2, 1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(hp.generator_size // 4),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d( hp.generator_size // 4, 1, 4, 2, 1),
        nn.Tanh()
        )
        
    def forward(self, latent, condition):
        vec_latent = self.latent_embedding(latent)
        vec_class = self.condition_embedding(condition)
        combined = torch.cat([vec_latent, vec_class], dim=1).reshape(-1, hp.generator_size, 1, 1)
        return self.tcnn(combined)

class Critic(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Critic, self).__init__()
        self.condition_embedding = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(hp.num_classes, 29 * 29 * 64),  # 64 channels
        )
        self.cnn_net = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(1, hp.critic_size // 4, 3, 2),
        nn.InstanceNorm2d(hp.critic_size // 4, affine=True),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(hp.critic_size // 4, hp.critic_size // 2, 3, 2),
        nn.InstanceNorm2d(hp.critic_size // 2, affine=True),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),   
        nn.Conv2d(hp.critic_size // 2, hp.critic_size, 3, 2),
        nn.InstanceNorm2d(hp.critic_size, affine=True),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
        nn.Flatten(),
        )
        self.Critic_net = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(hp.critic_size * 8, hp.critic_hidden_size),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),   
        nn.Linear(hp.critic_hidden_size, 1),
        )
        
    def forward(self, image, condition):
        vec_condition = self.condition_embedding(condition).reshape(-1, 64, 29, 29)  # Reduced to 64 channels
        cnn_features = self.cnn_net(image)

        print("Shape of cnn_features:", cnn_features.shape)
        print("Shape of vec_condition:", vec_condition.shape)
        
        # Check shapes before concatenation
        if cnn_features.shape[2:] != vec_condition.shape[2:]:
            raise ValueError("Shape mismatch between cnn_features and vec_condition")
        
        combined = torch.cat([cnn_features, vec_condition], dim=1)
        return self.Critic_net(combined)
```